# Laravel 5.6 - Model events: Can you combine static::creating and static::updating on one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have model events:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($questionnaire) {
        // Same code here
    });

    static::updating(function ($questionnaire) {
        // Same code here
    });
}
```

Is there a way of combining creating and updating together or is it better to put the same code in some sort of partial to reuse in each event?

Comment: Please fix your code example. I don't think you meant to put `static::creating()` twice.

Comment: Use static::saving

Comment: @Deven - Thanks, that's great!

Answer (score 9):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

> When a new model is saved for the first time, the creating and created events will fire. If a model already existed in the database and the save method is called, the updating / updated events will fire. However, in both cases, the saving / saved events will fire.

The **saving** event is fired when a model is being created or being updated.

Answer (score 3):

The saved method can be used to handle both the created and updated events:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saved(function ($questionnaire) {
        // Code here
    });
}
```

However, in the cases, when more than these two events should run the same code, you can use closures:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    $closure = function ($questionnaire) {
        // Code here
    };

    static::created($closure);

    static::updated($closure);

    static::deleted($closure);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go about it like so...

```
// store the events you want to capture
protected static $updateOnEvents = ['saved','deleted',...];

protected static function booted()
{
    // loop through them and apply the logic
    foreach (static::$updateOnEvents as $event) {
        static::$event(function($questionnaire){
            // your code here
        }); 
    }
}
```

Note that the `booted` method is available from Laravel 7.x, if you are using a lower version, you can use `booting`...